# rowcolors in multicolumn table

Tags: tables

i have problems to write a multicolumn table. The desired table is the following:

[image]

So far i can write the code regarding the multicolumn, but i cannot set the two different background colors.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ p{0.5cm} p{1cm} p{1.5cm} p{2cm} p{1.5cm}}
 & & \textbf{GALEN} & \textbf{GO-PLUS} & \textbf{SNOMED} \\
   \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{elk}} & average & 2004 \\ 
 & median  & 2005 \\ 
 & max  & 2009 \\ 
 \hline
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{owl}} & average & 2004 \\ 
 & median  & 2005 \\ 
 & max  & 2009 \\ 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{This is my one big table} \label{tab:tabGeneral}

 \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the rowcolor command from the `colortbl` package.

Comment: If you always have a word in the first column that should be vertically centered with respect to three rows, there is no need for multirow. Just place the wird in  the second row and it will automatically be centered. Also, why not use simple `c`, `l` or `r`  type columns?

Answer (score 1):

Like this? As you will see, I removed multirow because they are unnecessary when you have three rows per section. ALso, `p`-columns are unnecessary when you only have one line in each cell. Columns with figure should be set right aligned.
`
In addition, I added some more "air" in the table

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]

\caption{This is my one big table} \label{tab:tabGeneral}

\begin{tabular}{llrrr}
 & & \bfseries GALEN & \bfseries GO-PLUS & \bfseries SNOMED \\
   \hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} & average & 2004 &59140.0&997.8\\ 
\rowcolor{lightgray}elk  & median  & 2005 &&\\ 
\rowcolor{lightgray} & max  & 2009 &&\\ 
 \hline
& average & 2004 &&\\ 
owl  & median  & 2005 &&\\ 
 & max  & 2009 &&\\ 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}

 \end{table}

\end{document}
```